# white-space: pre-wrap with word-break: break-all recently became very slow in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

Switching to a jQuery UI tab with a `<div>` with lines that need to be wrapped and with the following CSS :

```
.console {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

has recently become very slow in Chrome.  This started happening with a Chrome update within the past 3 months or (I am currently on Chrome 49) - the same example still works very fast in both IE 11 and Firefox 44 (all tested on Windows 7)

See the following jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/7f7btvb6/3/ for an example.

Both Tab1 and Tab2 have both `white-space: pre-wrap;` and `word-break: break-all;` properties set.  Tab1 has 20000 short rows, and is reasonably fast (only slight delay when switching to it.) Tab2 has 2000 lines, but they require wrapping, and this takes a long time to display in Chrome - about 30 seconds on my computer.

Tab3 and Tab4 have the same data as Tab2, but in Tab3 `white-space` is set to `pre` instead of `pre-wrap`, and in Tab4 `word-break` is not set, and both these tabs display reasonably fast (about 1 second on my computer.)

Is this some issue with recent versions of Chrome, or some interaction between jQuery UI and recent Chrome versions ?  Or am I missing something or doing something wrong ?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated !

Edit: I updated the fiddle with Tab5 which uses `word-wrap: break-word;` instead of `word-break: break-all;` as suggested below and I also added some dashes to the sample text, to show the different wrapping behavior.  Tab5 is indeed as fast as Tab3 and Tab4, but does not wrap at the end of line like Tab2 does, which is ideally what my use case prefers.  But I will use this for now, as this style of wrapping is still preferable to 30+ second delays.  Thanks !

Edit2: I think this is not related to jQuery or even JavaScript at all - here https://jsfiddle.net/edpq5qcy/3/ is a new jsFiddle which is simplified to just the basic usage of `word-break: break-all;` - running this in Chrome takes 30+ seconds with 2000 lines, while in Firefox it is <1 second.  Resizing the window triggers the word-wrap recalculation, and another 30 second delay in Chrome, but nearly instant in Firefox, etc.  I feel like this must be a Chrome bug of some sort.

Edit3: FYI this issue has been fixed in Canary version 52.0.2712.0 (see [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=591793)) - it should hopefully make its way into stable Chrome release by end of July 2016.

Comment: I posted a bug on Google Development forum: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=603150

Comment: Any news on that issue... Chrome is still super slow compare to Firefox. I've got huge amount of code to show, and chrome is just a pain...

Answer (score 0):

It goes faster with this css:

```
.console {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

**demo**: [jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/fg097vdk/)

Comment: In my original case, I have both `word-break: break-all` and `word-wrap: break-word`.  Removing the first does make it faster, but also changes the functionality-lines do not always wrap at the end anymore like they do with break-all (the data displayed in the box is a log file dump with no spaces and mostly no actual words, just numbers and codes, so it works better if the lines simply wrap at the end)  It would seem that this should be the fastest option too, since no fancy wrapping logic is needed. But thanks for the suggestion, I might need to use this workaround for now.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround solution: simply insert `<wbr>` between the letters and get rid of any kind of breaker.

> The wbr element represents a line-break opportunity. [***- w3***](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/wbr.html)

Demo: [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/th7af7r2/)

Example of how to implement it with Javascript in an user-generated text box:

```js
document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("input",function () {
var stringtoarray = this.value.split("");
var output = ''
for (i = 0; i < stringtoarray.length; i++) {
output = output + stringtoarray[i] + '<wbr>'
}
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;
}
)
```

```css
#input{
  width: 40%;   
}
#output {
  width: 40%;
  background: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="input" rows="4" cols="50">InputTextHereInputTextHereInputTextHereInputTextHereInputTextHereInputTextHere</textarea>
<div id="output">Output</div>
```

Comment: it's not a solution for user-generated content which you cannot randomly add things to the string every N characters... most long content is probably user-generated and not a fixed-content by the system's developers.

Comment: Hello @vsync I updated my answer to cover user-generated content too.

Comment: By "user generated" I meant content which isn't yours (and is coming from an API). That content could be anything, from short text to long.